# "./src/**/*.{html,js}" in tailwindcss's content what does this asterisks mean?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Are this "*" mean anything like "." or ".." when we define path? I am not getting what those means. Why can't I specify the path in the **usual way**? I wanted to use paths like "../../XYZ" or something like that. But where is this asterisk coming from and what does it mean? Can I define the path in tailwind without using the asterisk?

If anyone can help I would be most glad. I am new to tailwind CSS so a little bit confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asteriks are used for dynamic imports for if you want Tailwinds to scan for content in any folder that is under `./src/` (asuming you are using `./src/**/*.{html,js}` as content in `tailwinds.config.js` file. That means if you use `./src/**/*.{html,js}`, the first two `**` will look for any folder inside `./src`, including subfolders.

So, for example, file path in your configuration file will most likely look like:

```
./src/**/*.{html,js}
./something-else/**/*.{html,js}
```

And these configured paths will "translate" to something like:

```
./src/folder1/file.html
./src/folder1/file.js
./src/folder1/subfolder/file.js
./something-else/folder1/file.html
./something-else/folder1/file.js
etc..
```

Which means if you add a file with the `.js` or `.html` extension in the specified folder(s), Tailwinds will automatically include these files in your project.

According to the documentation, you don't want to use really broad path configurations like `/**/*.{html,js}'` but rather use something like:

```
./components/**/*.{html,js}
```

See the [Tailwinds content configuration documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can use * to match anything except slashes and hidden files,
and use ** to match zero or more directories.

check this site it will help you:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration